# How to access return values from COM function in IronPython?

Tags: com, clr, activex, ironpython

I am trying to use IronPython to interact with a program which exposes COM API for many functions. The COM object handle is instantiated using following.

```
from System import Activator, Type
com_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Test.Application"))
```

Most functions fall into the three following common prototypes categories:

```
function1(BSTR inpstr, [out] VARIANT * outstr)
function2(BSTR inpstr, [out] VARIANT_BOOL * outbool)
function3(BSTR inpstr, [out] SAFEARRAY ** outlist)
```

When using **com_obj.function1**, I create a return pointer using following, and the output is as expected.

```
>>> outstr = clr.Reference[object]()
>>> com_obj.function1('Test String', outstr)
>>> print(oustr.Value)
```

For **com_obj.function2**, I am also able to create return pointers prototype using *clr.Reference* to get a return value for VARIANT_BOOL*.

```
>>> outbool = clr.Reference[bool]()
>>> com_obj.function2('Test String', outbool)
>>> outbool.Value
```

However, for **com_obj.function3**, and I am unable to construct a return pointer for SAFEARRAY** to access the return values. I tried the following, but it did not work. Also, I need to convert the SAFEARRAY** data to python list for further processing.

```
>>> mylist = clr.Reference[Array[object]]()
>>> com_obj.function3('Test String', mylist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Could not convert argument 1 for call to com_obj.function3
```

I think the last function (**com_obj.function3**) will not work unless I give proper pointers in IronPython describing SAFEARRAY** (array of strings?). I have struggled for weeks with this issue - and researching the internet turned up very little information - as IronPython is sparsely documented.

Any inputs on how I can get past these errors will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `SAFEARRAY` is not simply an array of "object". It is its [own data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/introducing-the-safearray-data-structure); in native code you create it using `SafeArrayCreate` (and clean it up using `SafeArrayDestroy`. Have you already searched or that in conjunction with (Iron)Python?

Comment: @Christian.K - Thanks for your response. I tried searching IronPython documentation - but could not find any reference to existing examples. The closest that I could get was to attempt using ctypes (both in CPython and IronPython) - to describe the structure as described in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/introducing-the-safearray-data-structure), but ended up with the same error. I suspect that the pointer types are not aligning - and since I am not an expert in CLR/IronPython - I could not go any further.